# Google Analytics - using properties

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a client who has a site (Website A), people go off to buy tickets on Website B.

I want to track the full experience using Google Analytics, so we can see how people arrived, how many people converted etc.

Now, to do this I think it would be best to keep the two Analytics profiles separate, so that my ticket pageviews have no impact on the main site. I can achieve this using Google Analytics properties under one account. Would you also recommend this as the best way or should I be tracking them under the same tracking ID or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be arguments for using just one property or for using two properties. 
You should give some more details on functions.

However I would prefer to use a single property for both sites based on your description as this would allow treat the user's journey across both sites in a more unified way, for example goals and funnels could be defined across both sites and you could have data from both in a single dashboard or report. You can also set two views to see each site separately.

Going the other way is not possible.

Finally - if you use Google Tag Manager you can change the setup from one to the other in minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Will definitely use Google Tag Manager as it seems logical to be able to handle various setups without physically changing the code.